# li's created extra while echo out simple-html-dom find

Tags: php

For a client, i am working out a way to pull his job offers from a different website to show on their own website. I use for this the PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser. This is the code.

```
<?php
$html= file_get_html("https://careers.smartrecruiters.com/ScandinavianHospitalityManagement");

echo '<ul class="career-list">';
if (!empty($html)){
    foreach($html->find('ul.opening-jobs') as $ul) 
    {
        foreach($ul->find('li.opening-job') as $li) 
        {
            if (!empty($li->find('a.details'))){
                foreach($li->find('a.details') as $element) 
                foreach($li->find('h3') as $title) 
                foreach($li->find('li.desc-item') as $tag) 

                echo '<li class="career-entry borders" style="height: 88px;">';
                echo '<span class="text-justify">';
                echo '<a href="'. $element->href  . '" target="_new">'. $title->plaintext  .'</a>';
                echo '</span>';
                echo '<ul class="career-terms">';
                echo '<span style="font-size: 11px;">'.  $tag->plaintext .'</span>';
                echo '</ul>';
                echo '</li>';
            }
        }
    }
}
echo '</ul>';
?>
```

I tested it out and it almost works as expected. Almost as in ... it creates between my active list items also a couple of blank list items, and I have no clue where these come from. I checked the code from the site I am pulling them from, yet it only shows me 13 different lis items. I have them all 13, with some extra empty list items.

example under here or via link: http://test.thewebfanatics.com/shm/wp/test/

[image: Error with blank created list items]

Also it seems to spit out only one tag (which is the last one), is there a way to make it toss in both tags, instead of just one by not having to enter a new instance? This is not a big issue, since I know how to work this with an extra instance, yet i'd like to know if there is a way to pull them out via not having to go deeper.

Comment: what is the site you trying parse?

Comment: see in the code, top line. https://careers.smartrecruiters.com/ScandinavianHospitalityManagement

Comment: The fact remains, even if I use a filter within the code to not use blank li's... (there should be at least an anchor with the class details in it, which i filtered out). Funny is that only the li's are created, not it's content, and if you look at the code, you see it should also create at least a span

Comment: Aren't you missing the curly braces around the last 3 foreach loops?

Comment: @chris no, its not needed with the simple-html-dom-parser. Dont ask why, but that what broke my head yesterday too when I started working with this script. See documentation: http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, looks like you need braces around the last `foreach`. Also, the list structure you're creating is completely invalid HTML. Try:

```
            foreach($li->find('a.details') as $element) 
            foreach($li->find('h3') as $title) {
                echo '<li class="career-entry borders" style="height: 88px;">';
                echo '<span class="text-justify">';
                echo '<a href="'. $element->href  . '" target="_new">'. $title->plaintext  .'</a>';
                echo '</span>';
                echo '<ul class="career-terms">';

                foreach($li->find('li.desc-item') as $tag)
                    echo '<li style="font-size: 11px;">'.  $tag->plaintext .'</li>';

                echo '</ul>';
                echo '</li>';
            }
```

Comment: Thanks for that fix. I know the ul needs a li ... yet, i hadn't come arround yet to fix that :) cheers and thanks for that headsup and having off course the simple thought of working that in the code itself. My brain is fried :P

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$html= file_get_html("https://careers.smartrecruiters.com/ScandinavianHospitalityManagement");

echo '<ul class="career-list">';
if (!empty($html)){
    foreach($html->find('ul.opening-jobs') as $ul) 
    {
        foreach($ul->find('li.opening-job') as $li) 
        {
            if (!empty($li))
            {
                foreach($li->find('a.details') as $element) 
                foreach($li->find('h3') as $title) 
                foreach($li->find('li.desc-item') as $tag) 

                if (!empty($element){

                    echo '<li class="career-entry borders" style="height: 88px;">';
                    echo '<span class="text-justify">';
                    echo '<a href="'. $element->href  . '" target="_new">'. $title->plaintext  .'</a>';
                    echo '</span>';
                    echo '<ul class="career-terms">';
                    echo '<span style="font-size: 11px;">'.  $tag->plaintext .'</span>';
                    echo '</ul>';
                    echo '</li>';
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
echo '</ul>';
?>
```

Realized I placed the check on the wrong point to see if the `$element` variable contained a hyperlink.